# Как найти первое вхождение строки и вернуть всю строку(в которой искали) до конца с места вхождения?

Tags: c++, строки, char

Учу С++ по книге Страуструпа, есть такое задание в конце главы :
"Напишите функцию char* findx(const char* s, const char* х) , нахо*
дящую первое вхождение С-строки х в строку s."
Я решил, что раз уже там тип возвращаемого результат char*, то функция должна возвращать оставшуюся строку.
Найти первое вхождение строки могу, но вот вернуть потом исходную строку с даного места не получается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    char* str_f = { "Hello, what's your name?" };
    char* str_s = { "your name?" };


    cout << findx(str_f, str_s);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int findx(const char* s, const char* x) {

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == x[0]) {
            int k = i;
            for (int j = 0; s[k] == x[j]; j++, k++) {
                if (j == strlen(x)) return i+1;
            }
        }   
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Сделал тип int, чтобы проверить правильного ли ищет первое вхождение строки в подстроку.

Comment: C++ уже не торт, лучше используйте `template class string` и выкиньте Страуструпа на помойку (впрочем, как и весь С++, но это отдельная тема).

Comment: При работе с С-строками вы не можете "вернуть строку". С-строка - это массив, а голые массивы в С и С++ не копируемы. Все, что вы можете вернуть - это *указатель* на начало найденной строки. Вот это от вас и требуется. Вместо возвращения индекса верните указатель на соответствующий элемент исходной строки - и все.

Answer (score 1):

Преобразовываем `const char*` в `char*` помощью `const_cast<>`, но лучше возвращать `const char*` и не использовать `const_cast<>`, если не хотим изменять константную С-строку

```
char* findx(const char* s, const char* x)
{
    char* r = nullptr;
    int length = strlen(x);
    int n = 0;
    int occurrence_len = 0;

    while (s[n]) {
        if (s[n] == *x) { //*x == x[0]
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
                if (s[n + i] == x[i]) ++occurrence_len;
            if (occurrence_len == length) { //нашли подстроку
                r = const_cast<char*>(&s[n]); //отбрасываем const
                return r; 
            }
            else
                occurrence_len = 0; //сбрасывем счетчик
        }
        ++n;
    }

    //если ничего не нашли, возвращем целую строку s
    r = const_cast<char*>(s);
    return r;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int findx(const char* s, const char* x) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (s[i] == x[0]) {
            int k = i;
            for (size_t j = 0; s[k] == x[j]; j++, k++) {
                if (j == strlen(x) - 1) return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
const char* findch(const char* s, const char* x) {
    int pos = findx(s, x);
    return pos == -1 ? nullptr : s + pos;
}
```

Вызов в main:
        cout << findx(str_f, str_s) << endl;
        cout << findch(str_f, str_s) << endl;